# htaccess - Migrating specific subdirecotorie(s) on a subdomain to a new domain with HTTPS and query string

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to migrate some applications from my server to a third party service on a different domain using `.htaccess` rewrite rules.  My goal is to preserve the functionality of old links and query strings with the new domain.

Example of old link

```
http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/mydirectory/*.*?query1=XXX&query2=yyyy
```

What I need it to 301 redir to is this link

```
https://newdomain.com/somedir/someotherdir/*.*?query1=XXX&query2=yyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of `mysubdomain.mydomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysubdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydirectory/ https://newdomain.com/somedir/someotherdir/ [L,R=301]
```